# How to insert row into table or add value if row already exists

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I'm making a C# based program which is using MySQL database to store data. I want to make an option to add row to table OR add value to row if it already exists. I tried to write this but nothing worked. I'm pretty new to MySQL commands so this might be obvious but I can't find an answer to my question. I think it's something like this (but like I said, I might be completely wrong):

```
if exists(update database.table set column = column + 1 where anothercolumn = something)
```

and then something to make the database do:

```
(insert into database.table (column1, column2, column3) values (a, b, c);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a unique key (unique index or primary key) defined on the table, you can use an INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement

```
 INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('a','b','c')
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col3 = col3 + 1;
```

Otherwise, you'll need to run two separate SQL statements, an INSERT to add a row, or an UPDATE to modify a row (just like you show except for the "if exists" stuff.)

The column already "exists" in the row, the question is what value is stored.

Comment: Yes, i have a primary key defined and this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The better question is *why* are we inserting a row whose key already exists?  Shouldn't the OP just consider updating where needed and inserting where needed?